# How to debugging and flashing Nucleo32 board from TrueStudio?

Tags: stm32, nucleo, truestudio

I'm trying to flash my code to NUCLEO-L432KC(STM32L432KC) by TrueStudio. It was failed.

[[image]

It looks tool cannot detect ST-Link probe. I just connected it by USB cable from PC (Windows10). Code and project file are generated by STM32CubeMX.

What is the missing? What should I do?

I have confirmed following.

- From STM32CubeProgrammer GUI, it cannot detect ST-Link connection.
- From STM32CubeProgrammer CLI, it can detect S/N of ST-Link. But cannot connect.
- From STLinkUpgrade 3.3.0, it can detect device and S/N. Also can update to V2J33M25.
- From IAR Embedded Workbench, it can build and flash code and debug. No problem at all.
- It looks same result using by STM32F4 Discovery kit for STM32F429 MCU.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have another program such as ST-LINK utility running while you use the debugger. Some versions of the ST-LINK "hogs" the debug pod access and other programs then would have trouble connecting to it.

Comment: I uninstalled everything that seem to be related, then installed only TrueStudio 9.3.0 and driver(en.stsw-link009) and STM32CubeMX-5.1.0-RC6. I also checked working processes. It seems no improvement...

Comment: Always go back to ST-LINK utility. Get that working first (e.g. able to erase chip and load a program). Go to Device Manager and make sure all the drivers are there. Make sure you see the ST-LINK debug pod listed as such, and that you have a VCOM port (it shouldn't matter for flashing, but lack of it may indicate something is amissed.

Comment: ST-LINK Utility works fine. And also checked detection of devicemanager, there is "ST-Link Debug". Btw. I have found a solution. When I use TrueStudio 9.0.0 it works fine. This means route cause is in the Stm32CubeProgrammer.

Answer (score 0):

Install the drivers https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link009.html

Choose the correct micro in the debug configuration window